# Como recuperar via C# o HTML de página gerada com AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angularjs, webrequest

Como recuperar o código HTML de uma página que utiliza o AngularJS para processar algumas informações e gerar um gráfico?
Consegui facilmente recuperar o código HTML utilizando WebRequest como demostro no exemplo abaixo, porém o conteúdo (gráfico) gerado pelo AngularJS não vem no código da página.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:36789/minhaapp#/index");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
string html = String.Empty;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
{
    html = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Falando de um jeito simples, o problema todo é que no seu código HTML tudo referente ao AngularJS é JavaScript. Quando você abre a página em um navegador o próprio navegador executa todo o JavaScript e aí gera o conteúdo do AngularJS que aparece na tela. Quando você através de uma requisição HTTP recebe o conteúdo HTML como string não existe nada para executar o JavaScript e fica só o código lá mesmo.

Comment: Exatamente o que o @Leonardo disse. O seu gráfico do angular é renderizado após o carregamento dentro do browser. Talvez você precise utilizar um iframe para solucionar este problema.

Comment: Com isto és capaz de conseguir: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem permissão para editar o site que gera o gráfico você deve extrair os dados do gráfico via JavaScript e enviar ao servidor, somente os dados, através de uma requisição http. Não é o ideal enviar html pro servidor extrair os dados.